# AnimatedContainer onTap animate once forward and back

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html

The example flutter.dev takes one tap to animate to a different look, and one tap to animate back to the original.
I was wondering, what if I want it to animate once forward, hold one second, and then backwards on one tap. Can I use a Timer to achieve this or should I be using AnimationController instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AnimatedContainer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html) provides `onEnd`, you can revese the animation from it.

```dart
child: AnimatedContainer(
  onEnd: () async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    setState(() {
      selected = false;
    });
  },
```

Also, you can use `AnimationController` with listener.

Answer (score 1):

The best choice would be using the `AnimationController` since it gives you more control over the object. One more important thing about using an `AnimationController` instead of a `Timer` is that the controller uses [TickerProvider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/Ticker-class.html) class for a more smooth start and ending animation.